# I want to color the send button on the mail edit screen with the Outlook365 add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am Japanese.
In Microsoft Outlook365, I independently developed a VSTO add-in as a countermeasure against incorrect email transmission. (.NET Framework 4.7.2  & C#)
I would like to decorate the "Send" button on the mail edit screen with coloring or borders in order to draw more attention from users. I want to know if it can be done and if so, how to do it.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVsKL.png)

It is known that opening the mail edit screen can be recognized by catching the event with the following code.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Outlook.Application.Inspectors.NewInspector +=
        new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(MyNewInspector);
    }

    private void MyNewInspector(Outlook.Inspector olInspector)
    {
        var olMailItem = olInspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        if (olMailItem != null)
        {
            if (olMailItem.EntryID == null)
            {
                // Open the mail edit screen.
                // I want to color the "Send" button in some way here!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At Win32API level, it may be a method of getting the HWND of the mail edit screen, getting the HWND of the send button with FindWindow() from there, and call SendMessage() to the button.
What would be the way to do the same in VSTO Add-in?
Is it a way to create own custom ribbon and embed it in an existing built-in tab? (In that case, I still don't understand that area at all.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no officially supported way to change any characteristics of the Send button.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding HWND - this is dead end IMHO. Ribbon is rendered using specialized office HTML rendering engine, and for the system it appears as a single window. All interaction happen inside it. There is no "handle" (HWND) for the button to SendMessage to. You can use good old Spy++ to see it for yourself.

What you probably could do is to add your own button (or some sort of indicator) that changes its color depending on whatever you want it to be dependent on. Creating custom buttons is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/ribbon-overview?view=vs-2019). To change its appearance dynamically you can use icon callback.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I decided to create a custom ribbon. I have added a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for advices.
I understand that there is no way to decorate the Send button.
I decided to create a custom ribbon and insert it on Outlook mail edit screen.
as follows.

```
Ribbon1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabNewMailMessage">
        <group id="MyMessageTabGroup" label="MyGroup" insertBeforeMso="GroupClipboard" autoScale="true">
          <button id="MyMessageRibbonIcon" label="MyButton" screentip="MyButton" size="large"
                   getImage="GetImageIcon" onAction="OnMessageRibbonIcon"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>

Ribbon1.cs
public class Ribbon1 : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
    private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;
    public Ribbon1()
    {
    }
    public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
    {
        this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
    }
    public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
    {
        if (ribbonID == "Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose")
        {
            return GetResourceText("OutlookAddinSecCommonCS.Ribbon1.xml");
        }
        return "";
    }
    public void OnMessageRibbonIcon(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
    }
    public System.Drawing.Bitmap GetImageIcon(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        return Properties.Resources.icon;
    }
}
```